# Powershell Script For Removing Users from Distribution list

Tags: powershell-2.0

Since I was notified I could not ask to write code, revising the posting. 
I have this code. It does run but does not pull any data into the cvs file or actually remove users from the DL. Not sure why its not working. This is run on an on-premise exchange server 2010 with exchange management console. Im pretty sure this is where I am messed up, but not sure how to correct it. where-object {($_.identity -eq "o365.test3") }

```
 Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 
#path to output file
$OutFile = 'C:\Scripts\Logs\' 
$OutFile_LOG = $OutFile+'DL_removeusers_'+$(get-date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')+'.csv'

$totalObj = @()
#get all distribution groups
$temp = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited | 
ForEach-Object { 
  #get certain user from Distribution Lists
  [array]$mem = Get-DistributionGroupMember -id $_ -ResultSize Unlimited | where-object {($_.identity -eq "o365.test3") } 
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $mem.Count; $i++) { 
    $member = $mem[$i].name 

    #remove user from distribution group
    Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $_ -Member $mem[$i].DistinguishedName -BypassSecurityGroupManagerCheck -confirm:$false     
    $obj = New-Object System.Object 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $_.Name -Name 'Distribution Group' -Force 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $member -Name 'Members' -Force 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $mem[$i].SamAccountName -Name 'SamAccountName' -Force 
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $mem[$i].identity -Name 'OU' -Force -PassThru 
    $totalObj += $obj 
  } 
}

#create output file
$totalObj | Export-Csv $OutFile_LOG
Read-Host -Prompt “Press Enter to exit”
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You shouldn't get help for that here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This one works but is doing 2x work. Just wanted update in case others having same struggle as I am to find something. Still working on the script..

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 
$members = get-content C:\scripts\dl\email.csv

Foreach($member in $members){

$DGs= Get-DistributionGroup
foreach ($dg in Get-DistributionGroup) {ForEach ($Member in Get-DistributionGroupMember -identity $dg | Where { $_.Name –eq $member }){ $dg.name }}

foreach( $dg in $DGs){Remove-DistributionGroupMember -Confirm:$false $dg -Member $member
}

}